# Convert from an unknown timestamp to a readable timestamp

Tags: mysql, ios, objective-c, ios7, timestamp

I have the below column containing timestamps retrieved from an `.sqlite` file,

[image]

what format are these timestamps in and how can one convert from them to a readable timestamp?

Actually if I knew the format of the timestamp shown I could figure out the rest.

I have tried pasting this in timestamp conversion tools online but the converter cannot identify the particular format.
I intially thought that the timestamp was in the format of `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS.uuuuuu` but the length of digits don't correspond to length of the format so I'm scratching my head on this one

Any help?

**Update 1**

These timestamps correspond to messages so its obvious that there must be atleast the minutes and seconds retained in that timestamp.

**Update 2**

These timesstamps came from a messaging application which I retrieved from a **.sqlite** file

**Update 3**

Based on the additional columns provided such as Name and message, I was able to verify that the timestamp correlates to the message timestamp inside the app to the `11/28/2012 10:48am` I was not able to verify the seconds.

Comment: You don't even tell where your data comes from, and you are asking what format your data has?  Duhhhh...

Comment: @BlueTomato Sorry, it came from a messaging application mate. I looked inside the .sqlite file and found that column.

Comment: Those numbers are not total seconds since Jan. 1970 unless dates in the early 1980s mean anything to you.  So who knows!?

Comment: They're likely seconds since January 1st 2001, also known as NSDate's reference date. If true then the timestamps here range from 2012-11-28 10:48:55 to 2012-11-28 11:25:43 (GMT).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

these are seconds passed since a certain time. Usually 1st of January 1970 0:00 is the first second. but in this case it would be a date that makes not much sense, as the first timestamp would be `Sat, 28 Nov 1981 10:48:55 GMT`. Tell us what the app shows for the fist timestamp and it will be easy to calculate the reference date.

possibly 1st January 2001, as it is another often use reference date. i.e. on Mac OS X and iOS.

```
NSDate *date  = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:timestampFromDB];
```

---

I wrote a test programm.

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        NSTimeInterval intervals[] = {375792535.395, 375792980.868017};
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(intervals)/sizeof(intervals[0]); ++i) {
            NSTimeInterval interval = intervals[i];
            NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:interval];
            NSLog(@"%@", date);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

logs:

```
2012-11-28 10:48:55 +0000
2012-11-28 10:56:20 +0000
```

for the first two timestamps. please check, if this are the dates shown in the app.

Conclusion:

The database holds double values to represent the seconds that passed since 1.1.2001 0:00 GMT, what is called the "Reference Date" in the Mac (OS X) world. The column does not hold a string with a certain format.

Comment: So the timestamp represents the amount of seconds passed since 1.1.2001 0:00GMT called the `reference date` and is not a format! That's really cool @vikingosegundo! I did check the application and after my findings I confirmed that the logs produced matched the timestamp on the GUI. So it definitely references from that reference date you specified! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use [+ (instancetype)dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:(NSTimeInterval)seconds](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSDate/dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970%3a) if the second is since 1970:

```
NSLog(@"%@",[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:375792535.395])
```

Output:

```
1981-11-28 10:48:55 +0000
```

It seems that your second is since 2001 (As mentioned by **@vikingosegundo** in his answer), so you can use

```
+(instancetype)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)seconds
```

Example:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:375792535.395]);
```

Output:

```
2012-11-28 11:24:51 +0000
```

And then you can use [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for formatting the date in desired format.

Comment: probably you will be off by 31 years

Comment: @vikingosegundo: the corresponding time to the given timestamp is that date, but if he is uses some other year (not 1970) as reference date then you are correct.

Comment: When he says that the data comes from a message application, what are chances that those numbers are total seconds from Jan. 1970?  Close to 0...

Comment: so what iOS chat app will have timestamps form the early 80s? Maybe some beta testers app?

Comment: read my answer, i think it is evident that it is the NSDates reference date. an that is 31 years later.

Comment: @vikingosegundo: updated my answer and +1 for notifying the issue :)